# RayCast Weapon Collision is not quite working properly

Tags: collision, godot, gdscript

I'm currently attempting to make an FPS in Godot Engine (Using GDscript), and I decided to use a raycast weapon because it seemed easier to track. However, when I check the collision and tell the enemy to queue_free(), it won't work. Hence why I cam to stack overflow, because it always has the answers.

PS, I'm using the print function to test firing because I don't have proper models yet, just a cylinder a box and some ground.

```
extends Node

class_name Weapon

export var FireRate = 0.5
export var ClipSize = 6
export var Reload = 2

onready var raycast = $"../Head/Camera/RayCast"

var reloading = true
var currentammo = ClipSize
var can_fire = true

func _process(delta):
    if (Input.is_action_just_pressed("LMB") and can_fire):
        if (currentammo > 0):
            reloading = false
            print ("fired weapon")
            can_fire = false
            currentammo -= 1
            check_collision()
            yield(get_tree().create_timer(FireRate), "timeout")
            can_fire = true
        elif not reloading:
            reloading = true
            print ("Out of Ammo!")
            print ("Reloading...")
            yield(get_tree().create_timer(Reload), "timeout")
            currentammo = ClipSize
            print ("Reload Complete!")


func check_collision():
    if raycast.is_colliding():
        var collider = raycast.get_collider()
        if collider.is_in_group("Enemies"):
            collider.queue_free()
            print("Killed " + collider.name)
```

Comment: There's a number of things that could be wrong, try using breakpoints and see if everything is being called as you expect

Comment: When you say it won't work, what do you mean? Do you mean it does nothing (including not printing the fired weapon and killed messages)? Do you mean it causes an error message? Do you mean something else? "won't work" is not a good way to describe a problem.

Comment: @Theraot Sorry for not specifying, it won't print anything or delete the object it's meant to delete.

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid First suspect would be the action. Are you sure `"LMB"` is registered in the project settings?

Comment: @Theraot yeah, because I use it for the other firing things and it works fine. It still does all the shooting and reloading, the only thing that doesn't function is the RayCast, not sure why.

Comment: Have the code print the collider name without checking the group. If it does not print, then it is a problem with the raycast, maybe the layers. If it print, then perhaps the problem is the group.

Comment: @Theraot thanks, I'll try it, in all reality I probably just messed something like that up... I'm quite new to godot and 3D development in general, so I'm still trying to get a grasp on it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of hard to tell from the information you have given, but my best guess is that the root node for your enemy scene is not the KinematicBody or RigidBody that is being returned by get_collider(). When using the get_collider() method it will return the physics body that it is colliding with. If you are checking the "Enemies" group for a physics body instead of the instance of the enemy, then it would return false. However, if my guess is wrong and the physics body is the root node, then I would suggest you add more context to your question.